# XAML to Html and vice versa

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, richtextbox

I'm currently working on a SilverLight text editor for my site control panel, I almost done with that, but now I need to convert `XAML` to `Html` and vice versa (as you probably know Silverlight's `RichTextBox` returns `XAML`) So I've to convert it to Html. Any idea how can I handle this ?

Comment: +1 for all. Thank you guys for all replies. But I found a good stuffs to handle this mission.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This tool allows you to enter XAML and have it converted to HTML, or enter HTML and have it converted to XAML.

[XAML to HTML and HTML to XAML Converter](http://windowsclient.net/downloads/folders/controlgallery/entry2313.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

This product converts C# and XAML to HTML and JavaScript.  It has a free edition that allows commercial use.

http://cshtml5.com/

A wide range of both .NET and XAML features are supported, which can be seen [here](http://cshtml5.com/links/what-is-supported.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

Well, it's just XML. So convert `Section` and `Paragraph` elements to their appropriate HTML equivalents (`p` and `div`, probably) and do so for the inlines as well (`Run` expands to just the text, probably, `Span` gets `span`, `LineBreak` gets `br`, etc.).

I.e. what you need to do is read the XAML as XML and create another document alongside where you write the elements as HTML. Applying formatting is a bit tricky, though, as you need to convert that to CSS styles (and maybe not everything apart from basic font properties works the same way in XAML and CSS).