# How to convert an existing "windows.form" or code in visual basic 2008 to any HTML code i want?

Tags: html, visual-studio-2008

I made a program in **visual basic 2008** and i want to use the same project but online, so for me to do that i need to **convert the codes or the windows form to HTML**.

IS there a way for me to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, write the HTML code and mimic what you see on your form. There is no automated way to do this because windows forms work differently than HTML forms. Depending on what you are doing there is no easy way to mimic its behavior and there might be multiple approaches. You might be able to use your original source as a backend.

There might be tools that will help you generate the skeleton.

Comment: What do you mean by “There might be tools that will help you generate the skeleton.”?

Comment: I mean what I said. You might find a tool which can help you generate the HTML skeleton. Either it might be able to use a XAML definition to generate it or just a regular WYSIWYG editor that allows you to quickly setup the skeleton pages. You will still need to put in the work to implement the actual functionality. See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8784563/xaml-to-html-and-vice-versa) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8921324/need-to-convert-vb-6-forms-to-html-forms)